# Need some assitance regarding header design for a website

Tags: php, html, css, web

[image]

Does anyone know how I can code the round icon along with clickable social media icons in the picture?

The site in question is: http://subwayisgay666.my-free.website/

Thanks for your help

Comment: That's not how this site works. SO is a FAQ for when you have issues with your existing code, and not _"I want to do something, show me how"_. That means that before you post a question, you need to have done the proper research and actually try something. If you then get stuck on something _specific_, you can come back, show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. Currently, this question is way too broad. I would suggest that you search for and go through a bunch of HTML and CSS-tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

This will be enough for you to start on the structure

```css
header > div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 955px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0 40px;
}
header .logo {
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
header .introduction .title {
  padding: 30px;
}
header .social, header .main-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
header .social li + li,
header .main-menu li + li {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
header .main-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a class="logo"><img alt></a>
    <div class="introduction">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">Joker, gentleman & student extraordinnaire</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="social">
        <li class="facebook"><a><img></a></li>
        <li class="google-plus"><a><img></a></li>
        <li class="twitter"><a><img></a></li>
        <li class="linkedin"><a><img></a></li>
        <li class="youtube"><a><img></a></li>
        <li class="behance"><a><img></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <p>Add your introduction text here. Your homepage should be the first page that visitors to your site see, so make sure you give a concise overview of who you are, what you do and why you are right for them.</p>
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Resume</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic questions since it legitimizes the question, resulting in the OP and future visitors to keep asking them. Doing so will most likely earn you down votes instead of up votes.